# Structuring a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object say:

```
{
   [
      {
         'name':'personA',
         'age':'30',
         'description':'some-text'
      },
      {
         'name':'personB',
         'age':'40',
         'description':'some-text'
      }
   ]
}
```

This issue is I need to be able to access each var by name, for Example:

```
people.PersonA.age:
```

so Instead:

```
people =

{
   'personA':{
      'age':'30',
      'description':'some-text'
   },
   'personB':{
      'age':'40',
      'description':'some-text'
   }
}
```

But then I cannot generate a list of names

What would be the best structure for this? I need to be able to loop though the names and quickly access the age etc using the name as a key

Comment: `But then I cannot generate a list of names` - why not?

Comment: @user1212520 what is wrong with your first JSON  ? Maybe the way how you want to acccess  it is not correct ?

Comment: If either example is a JSON, then they are malformed, both key and value must have double quotes. So these are objects, meaning they can be accessed as object literals, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this way of listing all names?

```js
var people = {
  'personA': {'age': '30', 'description': 'some-text'}, 
  'personB': {'age': '40', 'description': 'some-text'}
};

Object.keys(people).forEach(function(name) {
   console.log(name);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a list of names in the second form. Just get the `keys`.